# Is there a similar way to AlternateItemTemplate to do this

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, repeater

I know that with a repeater I can use `AlternatingItemTemplate` and `SeparatorTemplate` to adopt a variety of alternating items or for the latter a consistent style / attribute between items.

But in my latest task, I require a SeperatorTemplate but only after every 3 items!

I know I can do this in the ItemDataBound and have a cheeky `runningItemCount++` then use `runningItemCount % 3 == 0` to place this in.

I also know I can do this using a repeater within a repeater. *Just mentioning it is dirty...*.

I want to keep things clean to be honest, and if it's built in then it's something I want to get in the habit of using, so if anyone knows of how to do so in a nice way (no workarounds please), then please intrigue me.

Comment: mis-read the question, so I voted to remove my answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking in to this issue in various areas the conclusion in a nut shell is **'No there isn't'**.

I had to use the method I mentioned as unfortunately there is no specific built in feature for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this correct, but you can use `Container.ItemIndex` instead of runningItemCount  to keep track of the item index.

Comment: +1 I agree. I think I think the `Container.ItemIndex % 3 == 0` route is probably the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use the ListView control. It support a GroupTemplate and GroupSeparatorTemplate templates.